# SQL server querying

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to query a database and display information to a user after passing it as a Json object in asp.net MVC 4.

The only way I can think of passing it is as follows:

```
    public JsonResult Search()
    {

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from table", 
                                                   myConnection);


            SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                //Col1-7 are lists
                Col1.Add(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
                Col2.Add(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
                Col3.Add(myReader["Column3"].ToString());
                Col4.Add(myReader["Column4"].ToString());
                Col5.Add(myReader["Column5"].ToString());
                Col6.Add(myReader["Column6"].ToString());
                Col7.Add(myReader["Column7"].ToString());
            }
        return Json(new {Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7});
    }
```

The only problem is I don't want to use a heavy client side for this, and by doing this, instead of saving the datatable as a compact database, I'm saving it as a bunch of lists. Does this method defeat the purpose of trying not to save too much data on the client side (in that I am anyway, just not using SqlServerCe) and if so, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: 1) Do you need your Col1-Col7 anywhere else but in your json? 2) Do you really need *the entire table* on the client?

Comment: I need to display the data table so that the user can select certain rows that he wants, and I will not need Col1-Col7 later.

Comment: This may be what you want: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/24/JSON-Serialization-of-a-DataReader

Answer (score 0):

If you return JsonResult, use this:

```
JsonResult retVal = new JsonResult();
...
retVal.Data = new { col1 = Col1, ....};
return retVal;
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. What I can make out is that you don't want to display too much info on the client to the user?

While trying to answer your question I am also going to give some pointers.

Do not do data retrieval like you did from your controller.  Rather use a service layer or a repository to bring back data.  Lets say that you want to bring back all the users in your database, then I would have done it like this (just return what you need, the rest you can leave out):

```
public ActionResult GetAllUsers()
{
     List<User> users = userService.FindAll();

     var result =
          from user
          in users
          select new[]
          {
               user.Id.ToString(),
               user.FirstName,
               user.LastName,
               user.Age.ToString()
          };

          return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can put all this into your UserService class:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from table",  myConnection);

SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
     //Col1-7 are lists
     Col1.Add(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
     Col2.Add(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
     Col3.Add(myReader["Column3"].ToString());
     Col4.Add(myReader["Column4"].ToString());
     Col5.Add(myReader["Column5"].ToString());
     Col6.Add(myReader["Column6"].ToString());
     Col7.Add(myReader["Column7"].ToString());
}
```

Injecting your IUserService interface into the controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
     private readonly IUserService userService;

     public UserController(IUserService userService)
     {
          this.userService = userService;
     }

     // The rest of your action methods goes here, including GetAllUsers()
}
```